# Jekyll - How to set YAML front matter default for home page only?

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I am currently developing a personal blog using Jekyll (using [this blog post](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/) for an easy setup guide). I am trying to re-use an HTML file so that one url `"/"` displays some text while a different url `"/posts"` displays something slightly different. To do this, I am trying to set a [`Font Matter Default`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) in `_config.yml` that will only apply to one of the paths, the home path `"/"`.

Here's the code I'm using to set up the Font Matter Default:

```
# site defaults (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      display_num_posts: 5
```

The issue I'm facing is that `path: ""` applies to **all** pages, so my variable `display_num_posts` will be set to `5` on every page where my HTML file is used (both `"/"` and `"/posts"`).

My question: How can I set a path to only include the home page? With no extra `"/posts"` in the url?

I've tried searching on the https://jekyllrb.com/docs/ page, but couldn't find an answer. I also tried setting `path: "/"`, but that path didn't match any url at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this can be done by setting the `path` to the base `index.html` file like this:

```
# site defaults (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "index.html"
    values:
      display_num_posts: 5
```

I found this was possible on [this blog post](https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/front-matter-best-practices-in-cloudcannon/).

Hope this helps someone as it helped me.

Comment: This still wont work if you didn't add 2 rows with `---` on the top of index.html